# How can we edit the java.jar file? What tool we need to use for that purpose?

Tags: java, android

I am using the gcm.jar file in my android application. I need to edit the jar file (i.e.) to print some data using `System.out.println()` in order to check the flow of control. How is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to enable _logging_?

Comment: do you want to edit java.jar or gcm.jar?

Comment: @Swapnil yes, I want to enable logging.

Comment: @gigadot I want to edit gcm.jar file.

Comment: i think you are looking for an easy way which there isn't one. You need to extract the jar file, decompile the class file, compile it back and then package it up again. there is no editor which support this. including the source codes is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You have a jar file and you want to edit the code to enter print statements. Its unlikely that you will be allowed to do any of that. Its possible that the jar file has been encoded in a way to avoid decompile'in. Now, @Anup is probably right, you may need to look at the source code, if available. If not, you are in a soup anyway.

What you are trying to do is `hack` your way into the jar file, which is prevented, these days using class garbling techniques.

Answer (score 0):

u can edit the jar file by first decompiling it, use Java Decompliers
 
then you can add you code to the .java file
now repack or complile and build the new JAR file, use any IDE or even JDK with Notepad

Answer (score -1):

A jar is nothing but a zip file.  You can therefore use a standard zip-utility.  Also, the jar command line tool can also be used.

If you need to open it within code, there are various open-source libraries that can manipulate a zip/jar file or you can even make use of the build in zip utility that you can find in the java.util.zip package.

Answer (score -1):

A jar file is a Java ARchive. This can normally be openend with a normal Zip tool (7zip comes to mind). Though you will probably not be able to do much with the contents of that JAR. It probably contains .class files which are byte code and have to be decompiled. Try getting the source code instead, it should be easier.

You probably can better use a debugger to get the values you want.